# Elaborar subquery no mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Que traz a seguinte tabela

```
________________________________________
 id  |  descricao  |  ip  |  id_parent | 
  1  |   Teste     | 14   |   0        |    
  2  |   Outro     | 15   |   1        |    
  3  |   Meter     | 16   |   1        |    
  4  |   Tra       | 17   |   2        |
```

Tenho a seguinte consulta em MySQL

```
"SELECT  m.id
        ,m.descricao
        ,m.ip
        ,m.id_parent
        ,( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM medidor WHERE medidor.id_parent = m.id GROUP BY medidor.id_parent ) total
  FROM medidor m
  WHERE m.id_parent = 0
```

Que traz o seguinte resultado

```
________________________________________________
 id  |  descricao  |  ip  |  id_parent |  total
  1  |   Teste     | 14   |   0        |    2
```

Onde essa tabela é auto relacionada. A coluna id_parent é código do id principal e a coluna total é resultado de quantos outros itens estão associados a esse id.

O meu esquema está assim:

```
const MedidorSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        descricao:{type:String},
        ip:{type:String},
        observacao:{type:String},
        sn_capacitor:{type:String},
        sn_controlar:{type:String},
        ip_controlado:{type:String},
        sn_automatico:{type:String},
        id_parent:{type: String},
    },
    {
        collection:"medidor",
        versionKey: false
    }
)
```

Eu gostaria que viesse esse resultado:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("O1092kdsowo0203lldld"),
  descricao: "Teste",
  ...
  total: 2
}
```

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
return MedidorSchema.findOne({id_parent: _id}, (err, medidores: any)=>{
        MedidorSchema.countDocuments({id_parent: medidores._id}, (err, result)=>{
            medidores.total = result
        })
    })
```

Como faço subquery em mongoose?